# select last id has returned the same result for multiple requests

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to insert data into 2 tables where table2 has no primary key, but only foreign ones:

```
insert into table1 ....;
insert into table2 (a, column2, c) values(1, (select id from table1 order by inserted_at desc limit 1), 33);

insert into table1 ....;
insert into table2 (a, column2, c) values(1, (select id from table1 order by inserted_at desc limit 1), 33);

insert into table1 ....;
insert into table2 (a, column2, c) values(1, (select id from table1 order by inserted_at desc limit 1), 33);
```

and I ended up with the same id in the `table2` for `column2` in all 3 requests. Why and how could've I fixed that?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not inserting similar data in `table1` in all 3 iterations? Very difficult to understand unless you provide with exact insert statements for `table1` and explain how `inserted_at` is used in that. I guess you are inserting sysdate in that but without insert statements, we can only guess.

Comment: Use a serial column.  Don't calculate the ids yourself -- the database does that for you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

because you runing 3 inserting in the one transaction

you should add each befere insert `start transaction;`
and after each insert `commit;`

Comment: Not sure if that is correct. Within a transaction values should be visible. Most likely OP is using system date and all the inserts have the same value but can only be confirmed when full details are posted in the question.

Comment: @Neeraj: If `inserted_at` is based on the default `now()`, it will be frozen at the timestamp of transaction begin.

Answer (score 0):

consider doing this instead:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (a, column2, c) VALUS(1, (INSERT INTO table1 ... RETURNING id), 33);
```

Comment: that's neat. is it possible to declare a variable in pure sql instuctions like in my question and use it to save id returned from "insert into table1"?

Comment: Variable declarations come with PLSQL.

Comment: is it possible to declare a variable in pure sql instuctions like in my question and use it to save id returned from "insert into table1"?

Comment: You need to provide more details of exactly what it is you're trying to achieve...  if the data relations you are trying to create on each INSERT are overly complicated you will need to resort to PLPgSQL.  Otherwise using RETURNING with CTEs (WITH clause) should do the job.

Comment: there's nothing more you should know, it's a yes-no question.